# How to send Embed in Discord using bot coded in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, embed, discord, discord.js

I am coding a Discord bot to announce convoys for ETS2 but the bot does not recognise the command `const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()`. When I use the command in Discord to activate the bot (;convoy sim1), I get an error saying `TypeError: Discord.RichEmbed is not a constructor`. I have done my best to debug the code but have not been able to fix the problem. I have followed every tutorial on sending Embeds with bots but none have helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `discord.js` version 12 or greater, you need to use [`Discord.MessageEmbed`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor) instead of `Discord.RichEmbed`. From the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor):

> **WARNING**
>
> On the master branch, the receiving and outgoing embed classes have been unified; you will need to use `Discord.MessageEmbed()` as constructor instead.